# How can I Host a website with a Domain name just within the Local Network?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, apache-2.4, dhcp, xampp

I host a website on a local network with XAMPP. I usually access it with the IP address on another device.

How can I host my website on a domain like `website.local` ?
My OS is Windows 10 but if needed can switch to linux.

Answer (score 0):

This has, of course nothing to do with a business IT environment. A couple of tips, though:

Don't use ".local" domains in real life. They cause more trouble than they're worth. The yearly cost of a domain name is not high and will open up more opportunities to learn as a hobbyist.

To solve your problem you don't necessarily need to switch operating systems but to do it "as if for real" you will want to set up a DNS and you will need to learn about certificates and certificate chains.